# Drawing graph with Slider value in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM70l.png)

Can you let me know how to implement this dynamic graph in ios swift

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a Line Chart by following this tutorial then changing the display based on a UISlider.

[Tutorial link](https://medium.com/@tstenerson/lets-make-a-line-chart-in-swift-3-5e819e6c1a00)

Comment: While this may answer the question, posting links-only to other sites is a bad idea... links can go away. Either provide enough detail to make the answer useful *if the link becomes invalid*, or make this a comment, not an answer... review [answer].

Comment: Understood, I can't comment yet so I usually make answers :)

Comment: With Charts SDK implementation..X, Y coordinates showing improper upon slide value..any quick solution for it?